# How to scale down a game world (AR) without losing precision

Tags: ios, swift, position, scale, scenekit

I am trying to combat `z-fighting`, where the cpu/gpu has trouble rendering objects in a large world. As the math is now, the whole world is represented in `MKMapPoints`...and then there is a scale of `2.12732213757614 meters/unit` applied to that. This scale is nowhere near good enough to work without z-fighting. I have to then take the scale and multiply it by 1000 to get the z-fighting to stop.

```
scale = Float(coordinateConverter.unitSizeInMeters) * 1000.0
```

I apply the scale by dividing the various map point related values. For example, here I apply it to my position in the grid:

```
myPosition.x = (xValue / Double(topFivePoints.count)) / Double(scale)
myPosition.y = (yValue / Double(topFivePoints.count)) / Double(scale)
```

For these values, I would have a number like this:

```
-0.00041963615298460055 //myPosition.x
-0.00051179784578082345 //myPosition.y
```

The problem is, these numbers are too small to be detected by the game grid as a change. I have looked into it, and it isn't just the formatting of my numbers - I lose some precision somehow in the scaling process...so for the positions of the objects being rendered - they are represented by numbers like this:

```
-38144.5 //x
-46725.4 //y
```

The above number doesn't go to enough decimal places to have the difference between my position and the virtual objects be noticeable enough to the grid (my position numbers, i.e. `-0.00041963615298460055`, are too small to effect the numbers represented by the objects, i.e. `-46725.4`, because they only go to one decimal place, and the precision gets lost. Here is how I am changing the position of the objects relative to my position:

```
for node in scene.rootNode.childNodes {

    node.simdPosition = simd_float3(-Float(myPosition.x! - lastPosition.x!) + node.position.x, node.position.y, -Float(myPosition.y! - lastPosition.y!) + node.position.z)

}
```

For the above code, the scale is applied to `myPosition` (as seen in the second snippet of code above) when I receive a new proximity reading from an iBeacon.

The initial node positions are created like this (in a loop):

```
node.position = SCNVector3Make(-Float(transformerFromPDFToMk.tx) / scale + node.position.x, node.position.y, -Float(transformerFromPDFToMk.ty) / scale + node.position.z)
```

I haven't been applying the scale to `node.position`...and maybe I should be...but it appears to populate the objects according to their original scale because the objects are correctly spaced. `transformerFromPDFToMk.tx`/`transformerFromPDFToMk.ty` is the origin of my scene, relative to my position on the earth, in `MKMapKit` points. The object originally start at (0,0), so they have to be be adjusted to appear in the right spot relative to the world MKMapPoint coordinates.

My ultimate question is, how can I scale down the world without losing precision in the coordinate numbers for the objects (i.e. `-46725.4`)? Or how can I just take a chunk of the world I am in (instead of the whole world)...and keep the precision that way? The last code I will post is the code that I modified from this [cool open source project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/footprint/Introduction/Intro.html) regarding indoor positioning. I use it's `coordinateConverter` to get the values I need for the original transformation of the world (with two anchors for positioning and a rotation to orient the world). So maybe somewhere in this code I could break the world up into a smaller piece depending on where I am located:

```
...


init(anchors: GeoAnchorPair) {
    self.anchors = anchors

    /*
        Next, to compute the direction between two geographical coordinates,
        we first need to convert to MapKit coordinates...
    */
    let fromAnchorMercatorCoordinate = MKMapPointForCoordinate(anchors.fromAnchor.latitudeLongitudeCoordinate)
    let toAnchorMercatorCoordinate = MKMapPointForCoordinate(anchors.toAnchor.latitudeLongitudeCoordinate)

    let pdfDisplacement = CGPoint(x: anchors.toAnchor.pdfPoint.x - anchors.fromAnchor.pdfPoint.x, y: anchors.toAnchor.pdfPoint.y - anchors.fromAnchor.pdfPoint.y)

    /*
        ...so that we can use MapKit's Mercator coordinate system where +x
        is always eastward and +y is always southward. Imagine an arrow
        connecting fromAnchor to toAnchor...
    */
    let anchorDisplacementMapKitX = (toAnchorMercatorCoordinate.x - fromAnchorMercatorCoordinate.x)
    let anchorDisplacementMapKitY = (toAnchorMercatorCoordinate.y - fromAnchorMercatorCoordinate.y)

    /*
        What is the angle of this arrow (geographically)?
        atan2 always returns:
          exactly 0.0 radians if the arrow is exactly in the +x direction
                ("MapKit's +x" is due East).
          positive radians as the arrow is rotated toward and through the +y
                direction ("MapKit's +y" is due South).
        In the case of MapKit, this is radians clockwise from due East.
    */
    let radiansClockwiseOfDueEast = atan2(anchorDisplacementMapKitY, anchorDisplacementMapKitX)

    /*
        That means if we rotate pdfDisplacement COUNTER-clockwise by this
        value, it will be facing due east. In the CG coordinate frame,
        positive radians is counter-clockwise because in a PDF +x is
        rightward and +y is upward.
    */
    let cgDueEast = CGVector(dx: pdfDisplacement.x, dy: pdfDisplacement.y).rotatedByRadians(CGFloat(radiansClockwiseOfDueEast))

    // Now, get the distance (in meters) between the two anchors...
    let distanceBetweenAnchorsMeters = CLLocationDistance.distanceBetweenLocationCoordinates2D(anchors.fromAnchor.latitudeLongitudeCoordinate, b: anchors.toAnchor.latitudeLongitudeCoordinate)

    // ...and rescale so that it's exactly one meter in length.
    oneMeterEastwardVector = cgDueEast.scaledByFloat(CGFloat(1.0 / distanceBetweenAnchorsMeters))

    /*
        Lastly, due south is PI/2 clockwise of due east.
        In the CG coordinate frame, clockwise rotation is NEGATIVE radians
        because in a PDF +x is rightward and +y is upward.
    */
    oneMeterSouthwardVector = oneMeterEastwardVector.rotatedByRadians(-.pi / 2)

    /*
        We'll choose the midpoint between the two anchors to be our "tangent
        point". This is the MKMapPoint that will correspond to both
        tangentLatitudeLongitudeCoordinate on Earth and _tangentPDFPoint
        in the PDF.
    */
    let tangentMercatorCoordinate = MKMapPoint.midpoint(fromAnchorMercatorCoordinate, b: toAnchorMercatorCoordinate)

    tangentLatitudeLongitudeCoordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(tangentMercatorCoordinate)

    tangentPDFPoint = CGPoint.pointAverage(anchors.fromAnchor.pdfPoint, b: anchors.toAnchor.pdfPoint)

}

...

func transformerFromPDFToMk() -> CGAffineTransform {
    let metersPerMapPoint = MKMetersPerMapPointAtLatitude(tangentLatitudeLongitudeCoordinate.latitude)
    let tangentMercatorCoordinate = MKMapPointForCoordinate(tangentLatitudeLongitudeCoordinate)

    /*
        CGAffineTransform operations are easier to construct in reverse-order.
        Start with the last operation:
    */
    let resultOfTangentMercatorCoordinate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: CGFloat(tangentMercatorCoordinate.x), y: CGFloat(tangentMercatorCoordinate.y))

    /*
        Revise the AffineTransform to first scale by 
        (1.0 / metersPerMapPoint), and then perform the above translation.
    */
    let resultOfEastSouthDistanceMeters = resultOfTangentMercatorCoordinate.scaledBy(x: CGFloat(1.0 / metersPerMapPoint), y: CGFloat(1.0 / metersPerMapPoint))

    /*
        Revise the AffineTransform to first scale by 
        (1.0 / dotProduct(...)) before performing the transform so far.
    */
    let resultOfDotProduct = resultOfEastSouthDistanceMeters.scaledBy(x: 1.0 / oneMeterEastwardVector.dotProductWithVector(oneMeterEastwardVector),
        y: 1.0 / oneMeterSouthwardVector.dotProductWithVector(oneMeterSouthwardVector))

    /*
        Revise the AffineTransform to first perform dot products aginst our
        reference vectors before performing the  transform so far.
    */
    let resultOfDisplacementFromTangentPoint = CGAffineTransform(
        a: oneMeterEastwardVector.dx, b: oneMeterEastwardVector.dy,
        c: oneMeterSouthwardVector.dx, d: oneMeterSouthwardVector.dy,
        tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0
        ).concatenating(resultOfDotProduct
    )

    /*
        Lastly, revise the AffineTransform to first perform the initial
        subtraction before performing the remaining operations.
        Each meter is about (1.0 / metersPerMapPoint) 'MKMapPoint's, as long
        as we are nearby tangentLatitudeLongitudeCoordinate.
    */
    return resultOfDisplacementFromTangentPoint.translatedBy(x: -tangentPDFPoint.x, y: -tangentPDFPoint.y)
}
```

The above code is ultimately how I get the `transformerFromPDFToMk.tx`/`transformerFromPDFToMk.ty` to adjust the world. So, how can I scale it and not lose precision? Or how can I just take the relevant piece of the world?

**UPDATE**
I think I found a way to make it keep the precision, I had to move the whole scaling calculation into the `simdPosition` change:

```
node.simdPosition = simd_float3((-Float(myPosition.x!) + node.simdPosition.x * Float(coordinateConverter.unitSizeInMeters * 1000)) / scale, node.simdPosition.y, (-Float(myPosition.y!) + node.simdPosition.z * Float(coordinateConverter.unitSizeInMeters * 1000)) / scale)
```

Also, its kind of weird, I multiplied by the scale, then divided by the scale and I can see the small change is made in the number:

```
print("\(String(describing: Double(node.position.x))) --- node postion before didRenderScene: x")
print("\(String(describing: Double(node.position.z))) --- node postion before didRenderScene: z")

print("\(myPosition.x) --- my position before in didRenderScene: x")
print("\(myPosition.y) --- my position before didRenderScene: y")

print("\(String(describing: Double(node.simdPosition.x))) --- node postion after didRenderScene: x")
print("\(String(describing: Double(node.simdPosition.z))) --- node postion after didRenderScene: z")
```

the above statements return:

```
Optional(0.0011671428003945904) --- my position before in didRenderScene: x
Optional(0.0011160162812675013) --- my position before didRenderScene: y

-38144.5859375 --- node postion before didRenderScene: x
-46725.2734375 --- node postion before didRenderScene: z

-38144.58203125 --- node postion after didRenderScene: x
-46725.26953125 --- node postion after didRenderScene: z
```

So you can see the difference, when my position is factored in, is recognized between -38144.5859375 and -38144.58203125, and -46725.2734375 and -46725.26953125 - you can see the numbers change a little bit. I just don't see the change in my AR world though, the nodes stay exactly where they started. Could this be because I am formatting the `simdPosition` as `Double` before I `describe` it as a `string`? So the number changes because of the format, but the number representing a position is only allowed to have 1 decimal place...regardless of whether the number is recognizing the change.

Comment: probably simplest way to combat z-buffer issues is to increase near plane distance in camera. Too low numbers there will cause z-fighting.